# Finding Laplace Transform of a Function

Tags: laplace-transform

[image: From Adventures in Stochastic Process - Sidney Resnick]

Firstly, I believe there is an error with the function G on the problem. It should be:
$ G(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P[N=k]\cdot F^{k*}(x)$, where $F^{k*}(x) = P[X_1+...+X_k<x]$.
Because we don't know the distribution of N. Now, this is how I find the Laplace Transform.
$$
\hat{G}=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}[\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[N=k]F^{k*}(x)]dx
\\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[N=k]\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}F^{k*}(x)dx
\\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[N=k][\hat{F}(\lambda)]^k
$$
where $\hat F$ is defined as the Laplace Transform of function $F$.

Is my answer correct? I'm not sure with the second equality. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your integrand is non-negative, the interchange of integral and sum in the first step is justified by Fubini-Tonelli.

$F^{*k}$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $F$ (convolution in the sense of probability distributions).

Thus, the next equality is also correct, since the Laplace transform of a convolution of measures (a probability distribution of a real-valued random variable *is* a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$) the product of the Laplace transforms, i.e.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} F^{*k}(x)dx=\widehat{F^{*k}}(\lambda)=\widehat{F}(\lambda)^k$$